# list class property in a class c# assign value

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, c#-4.0, console

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Posting onjPosting = null;
        List<Posting> objList = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            onjPosting = new Posting();
            onjPosting.Key1 = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; i++)
            {
                Choice objChoice = new Choice();
                objChoice.ID = i;
                objChoice.VAL = j;

                onjPosting.GetPostingChoice.Add(objChoice); // GETTING ERROR [ Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ] 

            }
            objList.Add(onjPosting);
        }
    }
}


public class Choice
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int VAL { get; set; }
}    
public class Posting
{

    public int Key1 { get; set; }        
    public List<Choice> GetPostingChoice { get; set; }

}
```

While looping through and assigning the value I am getting error . How to solve this ? Please help me out .

My requirement is one parent class (Posting) , can contain number of data List .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: `GetPostingChoice` is null. Initialize it before using..... Better, learn how to debug a program....

Comment: What error? What value are you assigning?

Comment: btw. calling a property `Get...` is not good for readability of the code. One would expect a method and not a property

Comment: the error , Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Can you please help me out with the syntax to create a instance .

Comment: can you please share a example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never allocate the `GetPostingChoice` list so of course it is null.

You could do it in the constructor:

```
public class Posting
{
    public Posting()
    {
        GetPostingChoice = new List<Choice>();
    }

    public int Key1 { get; set; }        
    public List<Choice> GetPostingChoice { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a public constructor on your `Posting` class:

```
public class Posting
{

    public int Key1 { get; set; }        
    public List<Choice> GetPostingChoice { get; set; }
    public Posting()
    {
        GetPostingChoice = new List<Choice>();
    }
}
```

You also have other errors:

1. You do not initialize objList, so you cannot add in there.

   ```
   List<Posting> objList = null;
   ```

   So you will get another Null Reference when you get to:

   ```
   List<Posting> objList = null;
   ```
2. In your second loop you increase i instead of j so it will never end.

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; i++)
   ```

This is how it should look:

```
Posting onjPosting = null;
List<Posting> objList = new List<Posting>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    onjPosting = new Posting();
    onjPosting.Key1 = i;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Choice objChoice = new Choice();
        objChoice.ID = i;
        objChoice.VAL = j;

        onjPosting.GetPostingChoice.Add(objChoice); // GETTING ERROR [ Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ] 

    }
    objList.Add(onjPosting);
}
```

Since you ask for another approach, and this is just one of the many ways you could do it, have a look at this:

```
List<Posting> objList = new List<Posting>();
Enumerable.Range(0,100)
.Select
(
    (x,i)=>new Posting
    {
        Key1 = i,
        GetPostingChoice = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select((p,j)=>new Choice{ID = i,VAL = j}).ToList()
    }
);
```

Comment: There are many ways to do the same think. What would good mean to you?

Comment: Can you please share one more approach ? such that I have better understanding .

Comment: Better understanding of what? What you have done is pretty much clear and simple. Are there other ways? Yes there are, but what would you like to know better?

Comment: Actually I will be implementing the same on WCF . So can you please tell me about it's performance ? As their are other approach also available . if possible please share one more approach .